# widget binding vs scheduler binding in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to understand the meaning of widget binding vs scheduler binding, but I do still confuse about them. As I read a information, widget binding : `This is the glue that binds the framework to the Flutter engine.` but I can not fully understand what is `framework` and `Flutter engine` here. Can someone explain it in a soft way that easily to be understood

Answer (score 1):

**Widget Binding:** This is part of the Flutter framework that connects or "binds" the framework to the Flutter engine. It establishes communication between the widget tree and the engine. When you create, update, or remove widgets in your app, the widget binding ensures that these changes are reflected in the UI rendered by the engine. It acts as a bridge between the framework and the engine, making sure they work together seamlessly.

**Scheduler Binding:** The scheduler binding is responsible for managing the scheduling of tasks and animations in a Flutter app. It controls how and when different parts of the app are updated and rendered. The scheduler binding coordinates between the widget binding and the engine, ensuring that the UI updates are synchronized properly. It schedules tasks like rebuilding widgets, handling user input events, running animations, and more. Essentially, it helps maintain the smooth and responsive behavior of the app.

I put a URL for an example: https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-schedulerbinding-vs-widgetsbinding-149c71cb607f